# How do I factor something with 3 parts with a higher power than 2 and a coefficient in (a)?

Tags: factoring

I'm starting college this year, and I had to take a year off in order to collect some funds to help pay for it. I really don't remember how to factor something such as

$4x^2 + 4x - 35$

I know the answer to the problem to this question since it's a part of my readiness quiz study guide. But it was done in 1 step.

The answer to it is (2x-5) (2x+7). No other steps were done to factor the problem, it was just done in one step unlike the others such as $5x^3 - 20x$ which I understand how to do. And I understand how to do something like

$x^3 + 2x^2 - 9x - 18$. I can't really explain the terms used to solve something like this, but I get how to do it.

Another example of a problem I can't solve due to the rules of the formula is

$8x^4-17x^3+9x^2$

That ends up just becoming $x^2 (8x^2 - 17x + 9)$ but where do I go from there? I have to factor the same way just like in the $4x^2 + 4x - 35$ problem.

Can someone please explain how this is supposed to be approached. I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You can google "how to factor a trinomial" to see explanations and videos.

Comment: The short answer is that you should look for "easy factors."  By fundamental theorem of algebra, for a polynomial $f(x)$, if $f(a)=0$ then $a$ is a "root" of the polynomial, implying that $f(x)=(x-a)\cdot g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is another polynomial of smaller degree than $f$.  The easiest roots to check for are $0,1,-1$.  If you can manage to factor out some of the simpler roots and you are left with a quadratic, you can use the well known quadratic formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ to find the remaining roots.  Larger degree polynomials can be trickier (*and might not even be possible*).

Comment: Closed form solutions exist for finding the roots of polynomials with degree at most four, the formula for a quadratic almost being common knowledge.  The formula for finding the roots of a general degree three polynomial is much less common to know but exists.  The formula for general fourth degree polynomials would take several pages to write down completely.  It is a famous result of Galois Theory that there does not *and can not* exist a closed form solution for general degree 5 or higher polynomials.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you put dollars around the math it'll render nicely. If you want to do more elaborate things later see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @JMoravitz When you say "closed form solution" are you referring explicitly to the fact that there is no "general" solution? Just asking because I like to point that out as explicitly as possible; some people might take this to mean that no quintics can be solved.

Comment: @Ed_4434 of course.  $f(x)=x^5$ being an easy example of one which can be factored: $x^5=(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)$, but my point being, if you give an arbitrary polynomial $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ there is no easy solution.  Even given specific numbers like $x^5+x^4-3x^3+8x^2-x+5$, although we know that a factoring must exist, the factors themselves cannot be easily expressed.  If it happens to have one, it would be a special case and would largely be a fluke.

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed, I was just pointing out that the word "general" should've been included in there. :)

Comment: http://youtu.be/-RYPaC_hBUU  Be sure to read the comments to deduce how $49$ and $6$ is derived.

Comment: I was mostly hoping for someone to break down how to solve this problem specifically, and maybe I'd pick up on how to apply that to every future problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go over a known method which I know as the $AC$-method and will use your polynomial,
$$4x^2+4x-35.$$

The method is called the $AC$-method because assuming the polynomial is of the form $Ax^2+Bx+C$, we want to look at $AC$. For our polynomial, $A=4, B=4, C=-35$ and we see $AC= (4)(-35) = -140$.

Next, we identify two integers $X,Y$ such that their product is $AC= -140$ and their sum is $B = 4$. After exploring factor pairs of $-140$, we see that $X=14, Y= -10$ works since $XY = (14)(-10)=-140=AC$ and $X+Y = 14+(-10) = 4=B$. Now we use our $X$ and $Y$ to break up the middle term. From there, we group terms and factor,
$$4x^2+4x-35$$
$$=4x^2+14x-10x-35$$
$$=(4x^2+14x)+(-10x-35)$$
$$= 2x(2x+7)-5(2x+7)$$

Notice both terms have a factor of $2x+7$ we can factor out,
$$2x(2x+7)-5(2x+7)$$
$$= (2x+7)(2x-5).$$

This method will work whenever your quadratic is factorable over the rationals, i.e., it can be written as $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers.